# How to find pre-commit id covered by a new forced push commit id?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

I add my code change to repo, I can see the commit id by `git log -n1`.
Then I combine a new change to pre-commit id using `git add -u; git commit --amend; git push -f`.
Then I suddenly forget what's the diff with second change. But the pre-commit id disappers in `git log` history.
How to find the missing commit?

Comment: When you do `amend`, previous commit disappears. You're not intended to view diff between "commit versions", I believe. If you need diff, make separated commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: use the reflogs.

#### Long

The `git commit --amend` operation has the effect of "shoving the old commit aside".  If we draw commits, as found by a branch name, we get this kind of picture:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--branch
```

Each of the uppercase letters here stands in for a Git commit hash ID.  The *branch name*, in this case `branch`, holds the hash ID of the *latest* commit `H`, so that:

```
git rev-parse branch
```

prints out this hash ID.  Git is able to use this stored hash ID to read commit `H` from the database of commits.

Commit `H` itself stores, in its metadata, the raw hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  So having read `H` from the database, Git can fish out this hash ID, and use that to retrieve commit `G` from the database.

Having retrieved `G`, Git has the metadata from `G`, which gives the hash ID of earlier commit `F`, so Git can retrieve commit `F` from the database.  This of course has metadata, including the hash ID of another still-earlier commit, and so on down the line.

When we add a *new* commit in the normal way, what Git does is:

1. Write out a new snapshot for the new commit (we'll call this new commit `I`, using the next letter of the alphabet).
2. Write out the metadata for commit `I`: our name, our email address, the current date-and-time, and so on.  In this metadata, Git includes the hash ID of the *current* commit `H`, as the parent of commit `I`.
3. Use the internal version of `git commit-tree` to write all of this to the objects database as a new commit.  The act of writing the commit produces the new hash ID: the one we'll call `I`.
4. Store the hash ID of commit `I` in the *current branch name*.

Step 4 causes `branch` to point to new commit `I`, instead of to existing commit `H`.  When we draw the result, we have:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-I   <--branch
```

and as you can see, the process of starting at the end and working backwards will now find commit `I`, then commit `H`, then commit `G`, and so on.

What `git commit --amend` does is to *bypass* the *current commit* by having new commit `I` point directly back to the *parent(s)* of the current commit.  In this case, since `H` points to `G`, Git will make new commit `I` point directly to `G`:

```
            H
           /
... <-F <-G <-I   <--branch
```

Commit `H` *does* still exist, for some time anyway.  But there is nowhere to find its hash ID.  If it's still on your screen, or in scrollback in a window, you can grab it that way: Git *needs* the *hash ID*; a branch name is just a way to provide a hash ID.  If you can cut and paste the hash ID, that will do fine.

But here's what the word **reflog** means above.  Whenever Git *replaces* the value stored in a branch name, or in the special name `HEAD`, Git *saves the previous value* in a log.  **This log is optional** but it defaults to "on" for your repositories (at least if you use conventional Git; there are no guarantees if you are using Eclipse or JGit or some other non-Git program that merely uses the same database formats).  So when both `git commit` and `git commit --amend` overwrite the hash ID stored in the branch name, they save the *previous* hash ID in the log.

Running `git reflog` with no arguments will dump out the reflog for `HEAD`.  This is the most active reflog with the most "stuff" in it, so it has a lot more information to sift through.

Running `git reflog branch`, if you were on a branch named `branch`, dumps out the reflog for `branch`.  (If you were on `main` or `master`, use `git reflog main` or `git reflog master`.)  This will show the updates to that branch name.

In both cases, you can find the hash ID of the commit from just before the `git commit --amend`.  This will be the hash ID of the commit that got shoved out of the way.  So you can now run:

```
git diff <hash> HEAD
```

for instance to compare the two commits.

There are additional ways to use the reflogs.  See the [documentation for `git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) and [the documentation for writing revision ID expressions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).